# cannot install packages in spyder

Tags: python, installation, package, spyder

I need to use statsmodels, but i already tried to install it by spyder, with !pip3 install statsmodels
and i get this:

```
Python path configuration:
PYTHONHOME = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
PYTHONPATH = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
program name = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3'
isolated = 0
environment = 1
user site = 1
import site = 1
sys._base_executable = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3'
sys.base_prefix = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
sys.base_exec_prefix = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
sys.executable = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3'
sys.prefix = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
sys.exec_prefix = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
sys.path = [
    '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources',
    '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python38.zip',
    '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8',
    '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem 
encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000118d81e00 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

i also tried by terminal and it works, but spyder doesnt recognise statsmodels anyway. Both pip and Python are up to date

Comment: See my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66821271/spyder-ide-no-module-named-pip-on-mac/) for the proper way to do this.