# Spyder IDE : No module named pip on Mac

Tags: python, pandas, pip, spyder

I'm trying to use **PIP** to install **pandas** on **spyder** however I keep getting this issue:

```
/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No module named pip
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We don't provide `pip` in our Mac app to prevent people breaking Spyder by installing any kind of packages with it.

The only way to use other packages that don't come with our app is to install [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), create a [conda environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) after that with the packages you want to use and `spyder-kernels`, and finally [connect Spyder](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) to that env.

Comment: How do i create a conda environment ?

Comment: The link I posted above explains how to do it, but the simplest way is (after installing Miniconda) to open a terminal and run `conda create -n my-env spyder-kernels` to create an env with `spyder-kernels` on it. Then you need to run `conda activate my-env` and install the packages that you need to use (e.g. `conda install seaborn`, `conda install scikit-learn`, etc).

Comment: I need to install mini conda first correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to do that first. The first link in my answer will take you to the right page to download it.

Comment: And sorry for the huge inconvenience involved in making our users do all this by themselves. We plan to simplify the process and provide a simple, graphical way to create environments in the future (it's very high in our todo list).

Comment: After running conda create -n my-env spyder-kernels in my terminal I got this error "WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(50): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing." "environment location: /Users/opt/miniconda3/envs/my-env
  registry file: /Users/danielking/.conda/environments.txt"

Comment: Please uninstall Miniconda and only install it for your user. That could solve your problem.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Carlos is it possible to do a screen share with you?

Comment: We'll try to set up office hours for our users, so you can have a chance to interact with us live. Please follow us on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Spyder_IDE) for the details. We'll try to publish the announcement in the next couple of weeks.